# How to create a pkcs12 store where the private key is encrypted with a different password than the store itself?

Tags: openssl, pkcs12

Basically, as the title says.

Neither `keytool` nor `openssl` allow that.

EDIT: apparently, pkcs12 doesn't support that. So, use JKS, which you can easily create with `keytool`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What else are you even trying to protect, beyond the private key?

Comment: @CBHacking It's access control to the keystore content. I plan to have one big keysore with lots of private keys that I would share with different people. Nobody should have access to all the private keys - but only to those that they know the password for. Of course, everyone would know the keystore password.

Comment: If everyone knows the keystore password, and the private keys are encrypted with other passwords, what's the point of the keystore password? Are you just trying to increase the layers of passwords than anybody who isn't a part of "everyone" needs before they can compromise the private key?

Comment: @CBHacking By "everyone" I mean those people who need to access the content in the keystore. Keystore password is still a secret, distributed via a different channel than the password for each private key. The point of the keystore password is to not disclose ANYTHING about the content of the keystore (not even aliases), as that might give clues  to the bad guys for what the keystore is for, etc.